# Loading/Saving images misorder

Tags: c#, image, save-image, loading-image

I got a directory full of only PNG images (580 images).
I load the images in memory with this function

```
private List<Bitmap> images = new List<Bitmap>();

foreach (String s in Directory.GetFiles(@"frames\", "*.png"))
     {
        images.Add(new Bitmap(s));
     }
```

But after loading if I try to save all the images to hdd with this:

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("result");
for (int i = 0; i < images.Count; i++)
   {
      images[i].Save(Application.StartupPath + "\\result\\img" + i + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);
   }
```

Somes images are saved in the wrong order that they were before loading them to memory.

What might be the problem?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what tags are for.

Comment: When the order matters, I try to avoid using `foreach` as strickly speaking, it doesn not guarantee an enumeration in the order you expect. However, I'm not sure this is the source of your problem.

Comment: Originally ordered by what measure - name, ext, modified date, creation date...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to have file names sorted - you need to do it by hand since order in which GetFiles returns file names is not guaranteed.

I.e. simply sort by name:

```
foreach (String s in Directory.GetFiles(@"frames\", "*.png").OrderBy(t=>t))
{
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

visit this

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33310/C-Save-and-Load-Image-from-Database